# How can I show a field on load if a value is selected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that has 3 fields.  The value of 2 means that the code box `#canaddcodes`should be shown.  I have a script like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#canaddcodes').hide();
        $("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 2) {
                $('#canaddcodes').show();
            } else {
                $('#canaddcodes').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
            }
        });

    })
```

I know that the hide value hides that `#canaddcodes` but how can i show it on load if the val == 2?  I still want to show / hide on change.

Comment: Did you test this to see if it works? If so, what happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the `change` event on load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CodeSetup").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $('#canaddcodes').show();
        } else {
            $('#canaddcodes').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
        }
    }).trigger("change");
})
```

Better than put the whole `if` statement again outside.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Chain `.change()` to your change handler to invoke it on load:

```
$("#CodeSetup").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $('#canaddcodes').show();
        } else {
            $('#canaddcodes').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
        }
    }).change(); //<----
```